# Remove selection effect in input command

Tags: html, css, select, input, border

I want to have borders for my input box but i don't need additional borders when selecting it. I mean, before selecting the box, it is perfect but when you select it, some borders appear. i don't want them. you see what happens when i click the box:

[Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBVU3.png)

I want my box to remain how it was before clicking it

Answer (score 0):

In the image you linked to, I assume that the bottom part shows the input as you want it to be presented, with only a bottom blue border. And that the top part shows the input with a blue top, right, and left border that occurs when you click inside the input to type in it.

If this is the case, you can just apply the following css to your input:

```
input {
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
}
```

Comment: the problem is clicking on the box. after clicking, the borders appear. i don't want them. i just want the blue border. other ones should be hidden either before clicking or when clicking

Comment: Does the border appear even with the css I shared above? If so, please share your code. If you can't, then use a service like CodePen to show an example of your code, https://codepen.io/.